# Before-after slider does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to get an before and after image slider on my website using this code snippets from http://codepen.io/ace/pen/BqEer/ .

But it only shows the black and white image.

I put the parts together like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Awesome</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  
  <style>
   .before_after_slider {
     position: relative;
     margin: 60px;
     width: 640px;
     height: 400px;
   }
   
   .before_after_slider > * {
     position: absolute;
   }
   
   .black_white {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
  
  <script>
   var $black_white = $('.black_white'),
     img_width = $('.black_white img').width(),
     init_split = Math.round(img_width / 2);
   
   $black_white.width(init_split);
   
   $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function(e) {
     var offX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $black_white.offset().left);
     $black_white.width(offX);
   });
   
   $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function(e) {
     $black_white.stop().animate({
       width: init_split
     }, 1000)
   });
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="before_after_slider">
     <div class="color">
       <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/04/06/9pX4.png" width="640" height="400" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="black_white">
       <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/04/06/2sJzq.png" width="640" height="400" alt="black_white" />
     </div>
   </div>

    
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Removed unused css, added jquery and moved the script to the last.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Awesome</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
  
  <style>
   .before_after_slider {
     position: relative;
     margin: 60px;
     width: 640px;
     height: 400px;
   }
   
   .before_after_slider > * {
     position: absolute;
   }
   
   .black_white {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
  
  

 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="before_after_slider">
     <div class="color">
       <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/04/06/9pX4.png" width="640" height="400" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="black_white">
       <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/04/06/2sJzq.png" width="640" height="400" alt="black_white" />
     </div>
   </div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script>
   var $black_white = $('.black_white'),
     img_width = $('.black_white img').width(),
     init_split = Math.round(img_width / 2);
   
   $black_white.width(init_split);
   
   $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function(e) {
     var offX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $black_white.offset().left);
     $black_white.width(offX);
   });
   
   $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function(e) {
     $black_white.stop().animate({
       width: init_split
     }, 1000)
   });
  </script>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: NICE ! after i posted the question i thought the problem was, that you had to install compass/css. But this works perfectly. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad to be your help :)